# How do install Panda 3D on Precise or Quantal?

Tags: browser, plugins

I want to install Panda 3D (browser plugin) on 12.10 or 12.04 (32-bit). I have tried several things and tried to compile from source. Any source/compiled/ppa would be appreciated.

I keep running into 'pandas' on the web, is this related? It doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Both the runtime and sdk are now installable from the repo-please see my edit. I have changed the repo line, so that both will now be available: you need `deb http://archive.panda3d.org/ubuntu precise-dev main` in your `panda3d.list` now (and only that one).

Answer (score 0):

Panda3d works fine in Precise once installed, as you can test with this [example game](https://www.panda3d.org/gallery/demo.php?app=ball-in-maze) (screenshot below). Here's how I set it up, with reference also to [the official site](https://www.panda3d.org/download.php?platform=ubuntu&version=1.0.4&runtime) and [the useful forums](https://www.panda3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=14058).

1) Create and open your own list file with

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/panda3d.list
```

2) Now paste into the top of the file

```
deb http://archive.panda3d.org/ubuntu precise-dev main
```

Then save the file and exit `nano`.

3) Update your lists with `sudo apt-get update`.

4) Install panda-runtime with `sudo apt-get install panda3d-runtime`.

5) You should be able to install the **sdk** as well, either with `sudo apt-get install panda3d1.8` or `sudo apt-get install panda3d1.9` for the later version.

You will get a warning about the lack of authentication, as the site does not supply a gpg key, although it is run by Carnegie Melon University, so it is backed by an well-known institution.

5) Restart your browser and go to [the online demos](https://www.panda3d.org/gallery/); if they do not work in the browser straightaway you may have to download the file and run it on your desktop. You might get better performance this way anyway.

Panda3d game in browser:

[image]

Comment: This helps but I am looking for the sdk

Comment: @AaronSchif fixed- it is now installable from the official repository, just the same as the runtime.